# Why doesn't the Twitter user profile hover popup display when laptop is docked?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, multiple-monitors, docking-station, twitter

I have a new Surface Laptop Studio and a Surface Dock 2 setup which is working great with multiple monitors.

When the laptop is docked, I don't get the popup user bio when hovering on a username on Twitter. I have tried moving the browser window across all three of my monitors, but the hover never displays. As soon as I undock the laptop, the hover popup starts displaying again.  I get this same behavior with Chrome, Edge, and Firefox.

Does anybody have a clue as to what is causing this and how I might fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this same behaviour on my laptop, but not on my desktop devices (Firefox/Edge browser). In the end I found out that the culprit is the laptop's touchscreen.
If touchscreen is enabled Twitter will not display pop-ups when hovering. After disabling touchscreen from Device manager Twitter behaves as expected.

Perhaps when docked one of your input devices gets recognized as touchscreen (or similar) and causes this to happen? Compare the list of input devices when docked and undocked and try disabling the ones that are only present when docked and see if that solves the issue.